# Local to World coordinates in 2D and back

Tags: 2d, xna, mathematics, education

I'm getting back into hobby game programming after a long 4-year hiatus from college and I find that my understanding of coordinate systems is somewhat lacking.

I'm trying my skills at creating a simple skeletal animation system but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around converting local coordinates (of say, a joint) to world coordinates, particularly when it comes to rotated sprites.

I'm trying to create a test app in XNA and accomplish this using their built-in matrix class.  Can anyone assist me in either linking a resource or helping me understand the operations I'd need to do to convert any point that is Scaled/Rotated/Translated from a local to a world coordinate and back?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a good summary of how to go back and forth between world and local coordinates:

www.enchantedage.com/xna-transforms

Here is another good discussion of transforms:
[How to think about 2D scaling/rotation transformations](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3931/how-to-think-about-2d-scaling-rotation-transformations)

Comment: Interesting.  Thanks for the links.  After staring at this stuff all day I'm starting to wrap my head around the concept of Local and Global coordinates and how they relate to each other.